Need authentic references for the info provided in this article about hindu scriptures and Islam
I read an article about Prophet Muhammad and his family in which they claimed that whole family is mentioned in the hindu book barm uttar khand. And this book is mentioned in the book by sheikh abdur rehman chishti Mirat ul Makhlooqat. But i cannot find both of these book on the internet. Can anyone please find them or refute this claim. Link for the article: Prophecies About The Holy Prophet
I also need some reference about the facts quoted in this video about Hindu scriptures mentioning family of the Prophet Muhammad.
Would appreciate a lot if any of my Hindu brethren can find references for me.

Sorry we don't have any book called Barm Uttarkhand. And Allopanishad is written in Mughal court probably by a person who was forced to write so.
